# bootstrap icon for username and password

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, icons

I am designing login page. Here I am adding icons for username and password, when I add icons along with icons someother icons also adding how to resolve this . Here is my code.

```
<div class="left-inner-addon ">
            <i class="icon-user"></i>
            <input type="text" placeholder="User Name" name='j_username' >
</div></div>
```

and css is as follow,

```
<style type="text/css">
.left-inner-addon {
    position: relative;
}
.left-inner-addon input {
    padding-left: 30px;    
}
.left-inner-addon i {
    position: absolute;
    padding: 10px 12px;
    pointer-events: none;
}
</style>
```

and I dont have reputation to post pic of the login form .

Comment: Please provide a jsfiddle on your problem. I do not understand what it is about.

Comment: jsfiddle means what ? My problem is , icon is not displaying properly. In place of user icon it displaying 4 icons, which are besides of user icon in halflings image .

Comment: please set up your problem with your code and sample icons on: http://jsfiddle.net/ - this will help us to understand what your problem is. or you could upload your screen to a third-party software and post the link here.

Comment: It seems like your style "left-inner-addon" is creating a problem. I have removed it and it just worked fine. May I know why you are using "left-inner-addon" class ?

Comment: left-inner-addon class is to display icon left of the textbox . .

Comment: try to use `display:inline-block;` for both `i` and `input`.

Comment: @user3377978 Even without left-inner-addon you will get icon on left. See working fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/nareshravlani007/tHY2L/)

Comment: how to use , is it a tag . .

Comment: ya for me along with user icon it displays someother icons . .

Comment: yes I got it , can I get it inside text box . .

Comment: @user3377978 : Try card_master's solution. I hope it is what exactly you want.

Answer (score 0):

I got an idea of what you are facing, according to the current standards of Twitter Bootstrap, you just have to use the following code to achieve what you want. I had tested it on live server and it is working fine.
Just replace your HTML Code by the following code :

```
<div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="User Name" name='j_username'>
</div>
```

I hope this help.

Comment: no it doesnt worked, i just used <i class="icon-lock"></i> before <input> it worked but i want it to display inside text box.

Comment: Try a new code that I wrote in a new answer. Hope this one will help.

Answer (score 0):

I am writing a new answer for what you asked. Follow this code. This will definitely help.

Here's the HTML for the text box:

```
<div class="input-group">    
<input type="text" placeholder="User Name" name='j_username'  id="funkystyling" />
</div>
```

Here's the CSS for the image on the left:

```
#funkystyling {

    background: white url(/path to icon.png) left no-repeat;

    padding-left: 17px;

}
```

And here's the CSS for the image on the right:

```
#funkystyling {

    background: white url(/path to icon.png) right no-repeat;

    padding-right: 17px;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

With Boostrap 2.3.2

HTML

`<div class="left-inner-addon ">
    <i class="icon-user"></i>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="User Name" name='j_username' >
</div>`

CSS

```
.left-inner-addon {
    position: relative;
}
.left-inner-addon input { 
    padding-left:20px;
    height:20px;
}
.left-inner-addon i {
    position: absolute;
    margin:7px 5px;
}
```

[JSFFIDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/card_master/NnM8G/47/)